# Using a single pushbutton switch for 2 seperate circuits

Tags: power-supply, switches, circuits

I'm trying to rediscover my technical roots and am in need of some knowledge from experienced hands.

I have two toy sirens for my nephews pedal-cart, but I need them to both sound when a single push button is pressed (double the joy for my brother and his wife :) …).

Each siren has four types of sounds and the steering wheel only has 4 pushbuttons.
Each siren has its own (3Volt) power source so I can't completely take it apart.

I am struggling to apply Kirchoffs and Thevenins laws to this problem and want to ensure that I get enough current to the sirens (in case the voltages from the power sources cancel each other), but without frying the circuits (and ensuring that I've not series linked the batteries and delivered twice the expected voltage).

Hoping anyone can advise on the dilemma I'm having... I'd like to make sure that my nephew's first memory of "driving" is not one of fire and carnage.

Apologies for the simplicity of the problem in comparison to others listed here.

Many thanks.[image]

Comment: I don't think the circuit helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the sirens are identical, you should be able to simply parallel the switch contacts from each siren.  Be certain to match the polarity of the wires.

This will work quite well so long as the batteries in both sirens are (about) the same voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to source a double-pole switch.  I.e. a switch that will close two electrically independent circuits at the same time.   These are VERY common.     Describe what you want this switch to physically look like and maybe we can point you towards a good one.    Something like this should work for you:   https://www.ebay.com/itm/19mm-6-Pin-Dia-Double-Pole-Flat-Cap-Momentary-Stainless-Metal-Push-Button-Switch/263101029726?epid=8030268754&hash=item3d420b1d5e:g:Uj4AAOSwmT1Zets5

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsULeI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using a DVM to detect +V on the switch. Connect both to allow either switch to activate both or add a 3rd switch externally.